# netstat with grep is failing in Java

Tags: java

I am running the following code in cygwin on windows7 but it is not giving the output, can somebody help me?
And I used "netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED" through runtime exec() call in linux box and getting all other states but I need ESTABLISHED states only. (can somebody help on this?)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestNetStat {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -anl | grep 'LISTEN \\| ESTABLISHED \\| SYN_SENT \\| SYN_RECV \\| LAST_ACK \\| LAST_ACK \\| CLOSE_WAIT \\| TIME_WAIT \\| CLOSED \\| CLOSING \\| FIN_WAIT1 \\| FIN_WAIT2' | awk '/^tcp/ {t[$NF]++}END{for(state in t){print state, t[state]} }'");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the first point that your debugger shows you the program is not behaving as you expected?  What should have happened then/there, and what did instead?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `Process`? `getInputStream` returns the stdin. Try using `getOutputStream` instead. Docs:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: Check in first place whether the command is returning something when you run it without java program

Comment: @lucasvw, `Process::getInputStream` doesn't return a `stdin` - it returns a pipe linked to `stdout` of the process. `stdin` is returned by `getOutputStream`.

Comment: @SairamVinjamuri, check whether process's error stream has anything in it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov ah, so it does. Those method names are very confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I would read the input stream and also the error stream in a separate thread so that there is no blocking of the main thread, which would leave the programme in a hanging state.

First I suggest to create a method which creates and starts a thread and reads the stream:

```
private static Thread readFromStream(InputStream stdin, PrintStream out, String name) throws IOException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, name);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
    return thread;
}
```

And to use it you can use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
//            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -anl | grep 'LISTEN \\| ESTABLISHED \\| SYN_SENT \\| SYN_RECV \\| LAST_ACK \\| LAST_ACK \\| CLOSE_WAIT \\| TIME_WAIT \\| CLOSED \\| CLOSING \\| FIN_WAIT1 \\| FIN_WAIT2' | awk '/^tcp/ {t[$NF]++}END{for(state in t){print state, t[state]} }'");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k netstat");
        Thread in = readFromStream(p.getInputStream(), System.out, "in");
        Thread err = readFromStream(p.getErrorStream(), System.err, "err");
        in.join(1000);
        err.join(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Of course you will need to replace the executed command in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` with your command.

By the way: the `-l` flag does not seem to exist for `netstat`.